# WCF error time - Await Jquery Post

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

Eu tenho este método, que até então funciona bem:

```
$('#modelEditar').submit(function (e) {


$.post($(this).attr('EnvioLote'), $(this).serialize(), function (json) {
        if (json.sucesso == false) {
            $("#mensagemalerta").html(json.resultado);
            $("#alerta").show();
            $("#alerta").fadeTo(3000, 500).slideUp(500, function () {
                $("#alerta").slideUp(500);
            });
        }
        else {
            alert('Lote Enviado com Sucesso.');
            window.location.href = "/NFSe/EnvioLote/";
        }
    }, 'json');

    return false;
});
```

O que acontece, é que quando demora muito, pois está assinando um arquivo grande, ele retorna um erro 500. Eu gostaria que ele aguardasse o retorno após enviar para o `webservice`, pois primeiro assina, e envia, e caso seja sucesso, ou não, ele retorna. Para então mostrar o resultado.

Ele vai até esta linha de assinar:

```
 var assinar = await client.AssinarXmlRAsync(empresa.Caminho + "\\NFSe-LOTE" + model.IdLote.ToString().PadLeft(15, '0') + ".xml", "Rps", "InfDeclaracaoPrestacaoServico", empresa.Serial, Numero.ToString(), empresa.Pin);
```

E como demora o retorno, ele mostra o erro. Preciso que ele aguarde o retorno.

**EDIT**
Como estou utilizando `WCF` agora ele está retornando o seguinte erro, que era o que eu imaginei, o tempo:

> TimeoutException: The request channel timed out attempting to send after 00:01:00. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.

O erro dá nesta linha mesmo que informei, de assinar.

Comment: O erro 500 que você recebe vem com alguma mensagem?

Comment: Não, nenhuma mensagem. Depurando o código eu vejo que ele para nessa linha que mencionei na pergunta, e então retorna o erro, creio eu pela demora, ele precisa aguardar o retorno para mostrar a mensagem.

Comment: Quando é necessário fazer muitas assinaturas, por exemplo 50, ele demora, mas qndo é umas 15, ele obtém o retorno, e funciona sem problemas, só quando é mais que retorna este erro, e para nesta linha.

Comment: Entendi... Então nesse caso creio que esteja mais relacionado ao lado do servidor, certo? Não seria melhor então adicionar a tag [tag:c-sharp] e outras relacionadas ao seu lado do servidor?

Comment: @LuizFelipe eu mudei algumas coisas no código acima, incluindo o `async` e `await`, para agora o erro é do retorno do WCF, vou editar a pergunta.

Comment: Como padrão o `sendTimeout` do `BasicHttpBinding`e de 1 minuto, o que você pode fazer e passar um novo tempo de espera para ele antes da linha que você chama o método é colocar `client.InnerChannel.OperationTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);` neste exemplo estou passando um tempo de espera de 10 minutos, qualquer coisa também é só mudar na hora que for passar o Binding.